# How to drop constraint by name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How can I drop a constraint in PostgreSQL just by knowing the name?

I have a list of constraints that are auto-generated by a 3rd party script. I need to delete them without knowing the table name just the constraint name.

Comment: What version of PG are you on?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You need to retrieve the table names by running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.constraint_table_usage
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
```

Alternatively you can use `pg_constraint` to retrieve this information

```
select n.nspname as schema_name,
       t.relname as table_name,
       c.conname as constraint_name
from pg_constraint c
  join pg_class t on c.conrelid = t.oid
  join pg_namespace n on t.relnamespace = n.oid
where t.relname = 'your_table_name';
```

Then you can run the required ALTER TABLE statement:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Of course you can make the query return the complete alter statement:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||constraint_name||';'
FROM information_schema.constraint_table_usage
WHERE table_name in ('your_table', 'other_table')
```

Don't forget to include the table_schema in the WHERE clause (and the ALTER statement) if there are multiple schemas with the same tables.

Answer (score 18):

If your on 9.x of PG you could make use of the DO statement to run this. Just do what a_horse_with_no_name did, but apply it to a DO statement.

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
    BEGIN
        FOR r IN SELECT table_name,constraint_name
                 FROM information_schema.constraint_table_usage
                 WHERE table_name IN ('your_table', 'other_table')
        LOOP
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(r.table_name)|| ' DROP CONSTRAINT '|| quote_ident(r.constraint_name) || ';';
        END LOOP;
    END$$;
```

Answer (score 17):

Drop the right foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE affiliations
DROP CONSTRAINT affiliations_organization_id_fkey;
```

**NOTE:**

```
affiliations -> Table Name

affiliations_organization_id_fkey ->Constraint name
```

Answer (score 2):

List contraints:

```
SELECT con.*
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class     rel ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = connamespace
WHERE nsp.nspname = 'your_schema' AND
      rel.relname = 'your_table';
```

Remove the contraint:

```
ALTER TABLE your_schema.your_table DROP CONSTRAINT the_constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find constraints and Drop constraint  for required tables :-
in version 13 , tablename  is schemaname.tablename

1. get DDL  whole schema before  drop constraints , casacade drop all ref constraints  , that why need get all schema DDL

   ```
   pg_dump -h $pg_host -U $pg_usr -d dbname --schema=schemaname -s -f dbname_schename_ddl
   ```
2. get constraints details before dropping

   ```
   select  conrelid::regclass::text  tablename,  conname  constraintname,contype  
   from  pg_constraint where connamespace::regnamespace::text = 'schemaname';
   ```
3. Generate  Drop constraint scripts

   ```
   -- scriptsname mk_drp_tbl_cons.sql
   select ' alter table '||rtrim(conrelid::regclass::text)||'  drop contraint '||rtrim(conname) ||'  cascade ;' from  pg_constraint where connamespace::regnamespace::text = 'tax' and conrelid::regclass::text  in ('schemaname.table1','schemaname.tables2) ;

   psql -h $pg_host -U $pg_usr -d dbname -tAf -f mk_drp_tbl_cons.sql -o drp_tbl_cons.sql

   -- drop table constraints 
   psql -h $pg_host -U $pg_usr -d dbname -tAf -f drp_tbl_cons.sql -o drp_tbl_cons.log
   ```
4. add drop constraints , by running extract DDL in step 1 ( run multiple times make constraint before after is matching

   ```
   psql -h $pg_host -U $pg_usr -d dbname -dbname_schename_ddl
   ```
5. Validate constraint by running step 2

if not matching run step 4 again