# Find the name of the primary key constraint in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have an improperly defined primary key on one of my Redshift tables. I'd like to fix it. I can do this with:

```
alter table X drop constraint Y;
```

But this requires that I know the name of my primary key constraint.

I read somewhere that Redshift adds `_pkey` to your table name as the default name, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

I've tried querying `pg_table_def` but the info isn't in there.

Anybody know where I can find the name of the primary key constraint?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5273717/330315

Comment: Thanks. Figured it was simple.