# Modify UNIQUE in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like so

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS link_data (
            id                  UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
            connection_id UUID NOT NULL,
            the_link TEXT NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (connection_id, the_link),
            FOREIGN KEY (connection_id)
              REFERENCES connection(id)
              ON DELETE CASCADE
        );
```

I need to modify the table so it's only unique on connection_id, I.E. `UNIQUE (connection_id)` how do I alter the table to do it?

Comment: drop the existing constraint, create a new one

Comment: How can I drop the constraint without the name of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273717/drop-constraint-by-name-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop it by:

```
ALTER TABLE link_data 
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

then :

```
ALTER TABLE link_data 
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (connection_id);
```

you can check table constraint by :

```
SELECT con.*
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname = '<schema name>'
             AND rel.relname = 'link_data ';
```

Comment: In my case I don't have direct access to the production DB. So I can't check the table constraint name. Or is the constraint name always the same so I can run it locally?

Comment: @Marc Yes, if the `CREATE TABLE`/`ADD CONSTRAINT` statement didn't specify a name itself, the inferred default names are deterministic. (Not certain whether across versions, better check the documentation about that).

Comment: @Marc I guess the constraint name will be same.

Comment: So I tested

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE link_data 
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
ALTER TABLE link_data 
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (connection_id);
COMMIT;
```

But it did not work, I got the error "could not create unique index "constraint_name""

Where the constraint name was fetched in a local build. I then tried using the same constraint name in our testing environment where this crash happened.

Comment: @Marc did you check constraint name by the last query?

Comment: @Marc you can give it a green tick.

Answer (score 1):

First find out the name of the unique constraint:

```
SELECT constraint_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'link_data'
  AND constraint_type = 'UNIQUE';
```

or, using `psql`, simply type

```
\d link_data
```

Then drop the constraint with

```
ALTER TABLE link_data DROP CONSTRAINT whatever_name_you_found;
```