# How to disable only one foreign key check in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  bl_3nf.ce_sales     (
    sale_id                 BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    sale_dt                 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    prod_id                 BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_products (prod_id), 
    promo_id                BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_promotions (promo_id), 
    pharm_id                BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_pharmacies (pharm_id), 
    emp_id                  BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_employees (emp_id), 
    cust_id                 BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    channel_id              BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_channels (channel_id), 
    receipt_id              BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_receipts (receipt_id), 
    quantity_sold           BIGINT NOT NULL,
    prod_cost               NUMERIC(8, 2)   NOT NULL,
    prod_price              NUMERIC (8, 2)  NOT NULL,
    sale_srcid              BIGINT NOT NULL,
    source_system           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    source_entity           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    insert_dt               TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
    update_dt               TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ce_sales_cust_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id, sale_dt)
                    REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_customers (cust_id, cust_start_dt)
);
```

and want to disable only ce_sales_cust_fk when inserting into it.

It works with

```
ALTER TABLE ce_sales DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

And I know about setting role as 'replica',
but I need to disable only one fk constraint, to let others fk checks work and when I insert new data.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [How to drop constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273717/how-to-drop-constraint-by-name-in-postgresql) .  Why do you want a foreign key check when you disable it during creation of records?

Comment: Why would you need to disable that constraint? What data are you inserting? What other data would still need the constraint, i.e. why have it at all?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [deferring the constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) till the end of the transaction?

Comment: Just a guess, but Ithink likely. You need to disable that FK because it fails and you do not know the state of the others; they may have already been checked, but that is unknowable. It seems the `ce_sales_cust_fk ` would virtually always fail. Part of it `sale_dt` to `cust_start_dt` requires the rows to be inserted in **the same transaction** or a different transaction **within the same microsecond**.  The first perhaps, the second unlikely as not predictable/controllable.

Comment: @Belayer Inserting them in the same transaction (or referencing a customer inserted in an earlier transaction) seems normal and expected, not sure why you say it would "virtually always fail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have option like this :(

```
ALTER TABLE bl_3nf.ce_sales DROP CONSTRAINT ce_sales_cust_fk;
```

...do your job .... and

```
ALTER TABLE bl_3nf.ce_sales ADD CONSTRAINT ce_sales_cust_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id, sale_dt) REFERENCES bl_3nf.ce_customers (cust_id, cust_start_dt);
```

However, if you prefer not to disable the foreign key constraint, you could alternatively insert the data into a temporary table that does not have the foreign key constraint, and then copy the data from the temporary table into the original table once the data has been successfully inserted. This would allow you to avoid disabling the foreign key constraint on the original table.

Comment: Thanks, it's a better option then to disable all triggers. 
But how can I set a check that  cust_id exists in ce_customers table?
Not FK, since there are duplicates (it's scd2).
Maybe trigger before insert can help?